# Would like the tag field to not appear on the absolute bottom of my screen when in focus

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-experience

When I type a question, if it is more than several lines long, the Tags field goes out of view, a the bottom of the screen.

When I complete the question, I hit `tab` to bring the Tags field into focus.

At this point, the Tags field is on the bottom line of my screen. If I start typing my tags, the autocomplete options will not be visable to me.

So I need to scroll down a few lines before typing tags, in order to make the best choices of previously used tags.

I propose that when the focus goes into the Tags field, the tags field moves so that the scroll-bottom is several lines below the field, so that typing would reveal that autocomplete suggestions, without extra action needed.

In essense, one can tab to get the focus in the Tags field, and it seems to me at this point the Tags field should be fully usable. Currently it is not, since part of the use of the field is reading the autocomplete suggestions.

Comment: The tumbleweed badge! Woot!